# AWS Task Definition warning when enabled "Auto-configure CloudWatch Logs"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, ecs-taskdefinition, aws-networking

when I enable `Auto-configure CloudWatch Logs` a warning about Network mode appears, it says `Your containers in the task will share an ENI using a common network stack. Port mappings can only specify container ports (any existing host port specifications will be removed).`

[image]

This is the warning that appears, I don't understand what that means

[image]

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking-awsvpc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with the logging configuration. This has to do more with the networking option you picked (`awsvpc`). When you select that you are basically landing your task right inside the VPC and the task will get a VPC ip address. In other words there is no docker host natting where you expose the port `80` of your nginx container on port `12345` of the host. The warning is just saying that you need to make sure all your containers in the task do not overlap ports because they are reachable as-is on the VPC ip address assigned to the task. Note that `awsvpc` is the only networking mode supported on Fargate (because with Fargate there is not host anyway). See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-networkmode.html) for background on ECS networking modes.

Comment: I also think that it has nothing to do with logging, but it always appears when I enable CloudWatch. Not sure why but if it doesn't break anything probably it's fine